# Data Contracts and Circular References in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have class below but only the **SayHello** could work. Did you anyone know the reason?

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Department GetDepartment()
    {
        Department d1 = new Department() { DepartmentName = "dep1" };

        d1.employees = new List<Employee>() {
                new Employee() {
                    username="user1",
                    department=d1
                },
                new Employee() {
                     username="user2",
                    department=d1
                }
            };

        return d1;
    }

    public string SayHello(string username)
    {
        return "Hello " + username + "!";
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Department
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string username { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public Department department { get; set; }
}
```

The SayHello could works well but the GetDepartment is failed with error below:

*An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8080/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
Server stack trace: 
   at

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService1.GetDepartment()
   at Service1Client.GetDepartment()
Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
Inner Exception:
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
Inner Exception:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)*
```

Comment: To start with, did you debug?

Comment: Try turning on WCF tracing, may give you some indication to the problem: http://weblogs.asp.net/seaniannuzzi/wcf-diagnostics-implementation-in-5-easy-steps

Comment: It would also be helpful for you to post your WCF bindings...

Comment: Please post you IService code and the .config (or coded up bindings).

Comment: As a best practice, you may want to do this.    public Department GetDepartment()
  {
   try
            {
    /* your code here */
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionDetail detail = new ExceptionDetail(ex);
                throw new FaultException<ExceptionDetail>(detail, ex.Message);
            }
  }

Comment: Please post your IService.cs code.  Do you have [OperationContract] on all the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `IsReference=true` to your `DataContract` as explained here: [Data Contracts and Circular References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Department
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string username { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public Department department { get; set; }

}
```

The test client showing a successful execution of `GetDepartment()` method:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turning on WCF tracing will probably tell you everything you need to know.
I would expect you'll probably see something at the detail level which gives you more exception information once you open the WCF trace in the trace viewer tool.  My initial suspicion would be that you may need to declare KnownTypes for one or other of the classes.  The cyclic nature of Department containing Employee and Employee containing Department may also be causing a serialization issue.  I can't recall if I've done that before.

Look here for more info on KnownTypes and WCF :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If he was returning an interface or abstract class, KnownTypes may come into play.  As far as I can tell, he only have 2 simple concretes.  So I don't think that is an issue.  But your "cyclic" thing may be a good tree to bark up.